# Sending email through C# using gmail

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send email in my C# app with smtp.gmail.com.
My code worked fine until last week and suddenly I am getting an error message. 
I allowed less secure app in my gmail account, enabled IMAP, nothing changed.

The first verification works fine and I get "Port open".

Here is the code :

```
    using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            tcpClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            MessageBox.Show("Port open");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Port closed");
        }
    }

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myaddress@gmail.com", "mypassword")
    };

    using (var message = new MailMessage("myaddress@gmail.com", "toadress@gmail.com")
    {
        Subject = "Test",
        Body = "Hi"
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I get the error :

> "Service not available, closing transmission channel.
>  The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server 2a00:1450:400c:c01::6c (2a00:1450:400c:c01::6c:587), connect error 10061"}

Thanks for your help

Comment: try to check your code on the other gmail account, gmail might react to your smtp activities and restrict connections

Comment: Sometimes a 10061 error is caused by either a firewall or anti-virus  on the local computer or network connection.

I had a issue with school network, which couldn't send e-mails but at home I could.

Comment: Your first connection with TcpClient is pretty useless, why don't you just drop it? I don't know Google policies for multiple active connections from same IP. Assuming your TcpClient connection does not fail then you should check if your app is included in _Less secure apps_ list for GMail. Also check local issues, local/domain network policies may be blocking your connection.

Comment: @Vladimir nothing changed with other account

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I just added it now to check, not in use in the real program. I allowed less secure app in Gmail.

Comment: @TelmoIvo I though too that my school network is blocking it but I tried with my shared phone's connection and nothing changed too

Comment: Remember less secure app only works on accounts that don't have two step auth enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your OS firewall permissions. It seems like you can' t listen port 587.

Can you send your netstat -a output?